# Select this element in anchor in bootstrap using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
<ul class="list-inline list-attachment" id="listOfAttachments">
    <li style="display: inline-block;">Test2.docx<a role=" button"><i class="fa fa-close blue"></i></a></li>
    <li style="display: none;">
        <a role="button"><i class="fa fa-close blue"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li style="display: none;">
        <a role="button"><i class="fa fa-close blue"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select the button using jQuery. I 've tried a lot of  times, some of the samples are like:

```
$("#listOfAttachments > li > a > i")
$("#listOfAttachments > li > a > .fa .fa-close blue")
```

none of them works, some one can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I want to select the button using jQuery**: (Remove the `i tag` from the selector)

```
$("#listOfAttachments > li > a[role='button']")
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c5pxaa8p/

Comment: thanks for your fiddle. Actually I want to access the button (the class is from bootstrap). I don't quite get why match.length will work for a button with class="fa fa-close blue"...

Comment: The button is actually an anchor tag, matches.length is equal 2 because you have 2 anchors in your html which fulfil the selector.

Comment: I think the length should be three, right? cuz I have three elements fulfilling the selector. Why the first one is not counted?

Comment: Because there is a white space in the class " button" ;)

Comment: Just want to play around with it a little more. How do you think I could get access <i class="fa fa-close blue"></i> inside a? I tried $("#listOfAttachments > li > a[role='button'] ) > i .fa .fa-close .blue") but no luck...

Comment: $("#listOfAttachments > li > a[role='button'] ) > i.fa.fa-close.blue") should do it